# Will database upgrade break my page running on older Wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress, updates, wsod

Here's the situation:
My client's wordpress site just broke up (White Screen Of Death - I've tried every single solution with no result to fix it) and I decided to setup new, blank wordpress instance which will use old database.

When I've installed new wordpress (by uploading files to ftp) and add database info into `wp-config` file and then tried to log in I got the message: `Database update required`

My question is if I'll update database to new version will it work on old client instance eventually(just in case if their page will magically get to work again)? Or I should search for same wordpress version to install?

Comment: Which version is this WP?

Answer (score 1):

It should, that was probably what was causing the old site to break. One important peace of advise, backup the database before you do any upgrade to it. This way if something goes wrong, you can always start over.